# Semaphore is given although it is locked

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore, barrier

I'm trying to clock the time what it takes to get a semaphore when it is released by some other thread. So my vision is to create 2 threads and release the semaphore from a thread to antother, and clock the time between the release and acquisition.

Here is my code now:

```
void* semaphore_keeper(void* w_args)
{
  struct sema_mutex_args_struct* args = (struct sema_mutex_args_struct*)w_args;
  sem_t* id = args->id;
  int* status = args->status;
  pthread_barrier_t* barr = args->barr;

  while(*status != -1)
  {
    printf("keeper waits sema\n");
    sem_wait(id);
    printf("keeper got sema waiting for barr\n");
    pthread_barrier_wait(barr);
    printf("keeper waited barr\n");
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, start);
    printf("keeper sent clock\n");
    sem_post(id);
    printf("keeper posted sema\n");
  }
  return NULL;
}


void semaphore_mutex_not_empty(int w_iterations, int w_drop_cache)
{
  start  = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct timespec), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
  finish = mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct timespec), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

  sem_t* id;

  int* status = mmap(NULL, sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
  *status = 4;

  if((id = sem_open("threadsem", O_CREAT, 0600, 0)) == SEM_FAILED)
  {
    perror("sem_open");
  }

  sem_post(id);

  struct sema_mutex_args_struct args;
  args.id = id;
  args.status = status;
  args.barr = malloc(sizeof(pthread_barrier_t));

  pthread_barrier_init(args.barr, NULL, 2);

  pthread_t thread_creation;

  pthread_create(&thread_creation, NULL, semaphore_keeper, (void*)&args);

  double totSemaphore = 0.0;

  for(int i = 0; i < w_iterations; i++)
  {
    printf("mama waits on barr\n");
    pthread_barrier_wait(args.barr);
    printf("mama got past barr, waiting for sema now\n");
    sem_wait(id);
    printf("got sem\n");
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, finish);
    double thisTime = (finish->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec);
    totSemaphore += (finish->tv_nsec - start->tv_nsec);
    printf("%f\n", thisTime);
    printf("mama posting sema\n");
    sem_post(id);
  }
  // very ugly
  *status = -1;
  pthread_join(thread_creation, NULL);

....
```

I think this code should work so the barriers make the threads wait for each other so it won't get desynced. However, when I run the program, the output I get is as shown below (the first iteration):

```
mama waits on barr
keeper waits sema
keeper got sema waiting for barr
keeper waited barr
mama got past barr, waiting for sema now
got sem
keeper sent clock
keeper posted sema
keeper waits sema
keeper got sema waiting for barr
-1567.000000
```

So the threads wait for each other at the barrier just as they should, but seems like that the main thread gets the semaphore even before the child thread releases it. Why is that? What am I doing wrong? As said, the reference output is from the first iteration only. It seems to get fixed (at least gives positive values) after the first iteration, but I would not believe they are right values either, as it is getting messed up already in the very first iteration too.

Comment: sem_wait(id) and friends  can fail. and can still print those statements your codes doesn't take care of that.

Comment: So you're saying that the wait fails in the child class if it is not yet initialized in the main thread? Good point, I'll check that.

Comment: @potato I checked and none of the sem calls (sem_wait and sem_post) returned an error. Now I'm starting to doubt if the whole semaphore is implemented wrong here.

Comment: POSIX named semaphores are persistent until system reboot, so, especially if you've previously run your program and killed it, it's possible that your `sem_open` call returns a semaphore initialized to something other than zero.  That's not the only problem here, but it would be good to eliminate it by calling `sem_open(..., O_CREAT|O_EXCL, ..., 0)`.

Comment: @pilcrow that is the problem! How can I completely remove semaphore? I thought sem_close() is enough... Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Try [`sem_unlink`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_unlink.html) before the open.  Do also use O_EXCL for good measure — it will explode if, e.g., another instance of the program is unexpectedly running alongside you.

Comment: Thanks @pilcrow. Your advices were golden.